# EC2を作成する際に作成したセキュリティーグループが選択できない。

Tags: amazon-ec2

EC2を作成する際に作成したセキュリティーグループが選択できません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

セキュリティグループは厳密にはEC2インスタンスに紐付けられるわけではありません。[セキュリティグループはネットワークインターフェイスに関連付けられます。](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html#:%7E:text=%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%81%AF%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E9%96%A2%E9%80%A3%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82)
ですので、EC2インスタンス作成時に、デフォルトのネットワークインターフェイスを指定するとデフォルトのセキュリティグループになってしまいます。

明示的にセキュリティグループを指定するためには、明示的にネットワークインターフェイスを作成する必要があります。
なお、ネットワークインターフェース自体はいずれかのサブネットに所属するため、サブネットも明示的に指定する必要があります。

Comment: ご指摘いただきました通り、EC2インスタンスの作成時に、デフォルトのネットワークインターフェースを指定しておりました。解決いたしました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @13434 解決したのであれば[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)をお願いします。